# Multiplying multidimensional array column by rows

Tags: java

I have the following arrays in java, i would like to multiply array_x columns by array_y rows to finally create array_z values

```
aray_x        array_y            array_z

4|9          4|11|12|14             |
---          ----------           -----
8|7          13|9|22|7              | 
---                               -----
3|2                                 | 
---                               -----  
9|1                                 |
```

my trial code listing
public class Multiplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array_x[][] = {{9, 8}, {2, 17}, {49, 4}, {13, 119}, {2, 19}, {11, 47}, {3, 73}};
    int[][] array_y = new int[][]{{4, 11, 12, 14}, {13, 9, 22, 7}};
    int array_z[][] = new int[4][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < array_x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array_x.length; j++) {
            array_z[i][j] = array_x[i][j] * array_y[j][i];
                System.out.print(" "+array_z[i][j]);
        }

    }

}
```

}

How do i achieve this - That;
The 1st column of array_z is populated by the multiples of the 1st column of array_x and the 1st row of array_y. e.g 4x4=16, 8x11=88, thius array_x * array_y =array_z
The 2nd column of array_z is populated by the multiples of the 2nd column of array_x and the 2nd row of array_y.

Comment: Can you clarify the matrix dimensions? if rx=7, cx=2, ry=2 and cy=4 (as in your example), what do you expect the dimsions rz and cz? Is z[i,j] = Sum(x[i,k]*y[k*j])? If you formulate it this way, you have a simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: array x has 4 rows and 2 columns while array y has 2 rows and 4 columns, i would like to multiply column x by row y

Comment: So you are trying Z = Y*X, in terms of matrix multiplication...

Comment: Just answered with the pseudocode - hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, i have refined the question, hope you understand it now well

Comment: I have added the code listing, still does not reach the goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete class to compile and run, with your data... hope this helps

```
public class Alphy {

    private double[][] x;

    public Alphy (double[][] x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double[][] multiplyWith (double[][] y) {
        int nr = x.length, nc = x[0].length;
        double[][] z = new double[nr][nc];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < nr ; i++)
            for (int j = 0 ; j < nc ; j++)
                z[i][j] = x[i][j] * y[j][i];
        return z;
    }

    public static void print (double[][] m, String label) {
        int nr = m.length, nc = m[0].length;
        System.out.println (label);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < nr ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < nc ; j++)
                System.out.print ("\t" + m[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
    }}

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double[][]  X = {{4, 9}, {8, 7}, {3, 2}, {9, 1}},
                Y = {{4, 11, 12, 14}, {13, 9, 22, 7}},
                Z = new Alphy(X).multiplyWith(Y);
        Alphy.print (X, "Initial Matrix");
        Alphy.print (Y, "Multiplied by");
        Alphy.print (Z, "Gives the result");
}}
/* Output of the above class:

Initial Matrix
    4.0 9.0
    8.0 7.0
    3.0 2.0
    9.0 1.0
Multiplied by
    4.0 11.0    12.0    14.0
    13.0    9.0 22.0    7.0
Gives the result
    16.0    117.0
    88.0    63.0
    36.0    44.0
    126.0   7.0
*/
```

Comment: Thank you Manidip that worked, could you comment the your code listing

Comment: this does not seem to be right , the result of the initial and multiplied matrix will be with 4 rows and 4 columns . correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My Math is a bit rusty, but is this the correct answer?

```
    int array_x[][] = {{4, 9}, {8, 7}, {3, 2}, {9, 1}};
    int array_y[][] = {{4, 11, 12, 14}, {13, 9, 22, 7}};

    int array_z[][] = new int[array_x[0].length][array_y.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array_x[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array_y.length; j++) {
            if (array_x.length != array_y[i].length) {
                System.out.println("Dimention missmatch " + array_x.length +" vs "+ array_y[i].length);
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < array_x.length; k++) {
                sum += array_x[k][i] * array_y[j][k];
             //   System.out.println(i+"\t"+ j +"\t"+k+"\t"+  array_x[k][i] +"\t"+  array_y[j][k] +"\t"+  sum+"\t");
            }
           // System.out.println();
            array_z[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array_z));
```

Output:

```
[[266, 253], [151, 231]]
```

Or do you need a 4X4 matrix as a result?